# Why is Java Graphics2D 'drawString' stopping repaint()?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm currently in the process of creating a game with Java Swing. I need a score counter, so I'm using the Graphics2D method `drawString` to draw it.

I have removed everything that doesn't change the problem in my code, and eventually I found out the problem was the `drawString` method.

This is my full code: (Problem/src/defaultpackage/Problem.java)

```
// All the imports are here
public class Problem extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Problem problem = new Problem();
        frame.add(problem);

        frame.setTitle("Problem");
        frame.setSize(350, 720);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.requestFocus();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public Problem() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleTask(),0,20);
        // Changing '20' doesn't work
    }
    private void draw(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("draw");
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawString("S", 100, 100);
        // If I remove this and replace it by:
        //g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        // it works just fine
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("paintcomponent");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }
    private class ScheduleTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("repaint");
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
repaint
paintcomponent
draw
repaint
paintcomponent
draw
```

and so on. But instead, for the first two seconds that the programm is running, the output is just:

```
repaint
repaint
repaint
```

And after that two seconds everything works as expected.

Why would this happen?

Comment: Do you have any idea how long it takes before the GUI is ready?

Comment: GUI is ready when `setVisible(true)` has been called. Nothing is visible, i.e. needs repainting, until then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the timer runs 50 times per second, so fires many times before the main thread completes the GUI initialization.

Calling `repaint()` before GUI is ready doesn't cause `paintComponent()` to be called.

If you don't start the timer until after `setVisible(true)` has been called, you get what you expected.

Comment: But if I replace `drawString` by `fillRect`, it works immediately. Why would that be?

Comment: @DanDeg Maybe because `drawString` needs to load the font files, and that takes a minute, but measurable, amount of time?

Comment: That's probably it. Thanks!